# PHP + MySQL user defined function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to print all sub-category items using my own defined PHP function. The purpose of this function is to print all items, which parent value is `$parent`.
There is something wrong with this function why it doesn't show information as I wish. To make you understand my aim, suppose that we've items categorized in different groups each has own groups ID. Calling this function I wish to get the all items of same group by feeding of group Id as argument `$parent`.
Could someone help me to find out the reason why this function doesn’t work, please. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');
include ('head.html');

echo '<div class="categ"><p class="b">Health</p>';
function retrieve_column($parent){
    $sql = "SELECT item FROM category WHERE parent = $parent ORDER BY item ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        if (!$r) {
            echo "Couldn’t make a connection to DB.";
        } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                for ($i=0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($r); $i++) {
                    echo '<a class="text" href="">' . $row['item'][$i] . '</a><br />';
                }
            }
        }
    }

$par = 1;
retrieve_column($par);
mysqli_free_r($r);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: What are the expected result and the actual result?

Comment: You should use prepared statements and you will avioid SQL injection and problems like this. You need single quotes for the $parent variable like **parent = '$parent'**

Comment: Thanks @FrancescoManicardi for your reacting. I suppose to expect a result like following: `Surgery<br />
Physiology
Psychology
Urgent care
Cardiology
Chronic treatment
Pharmacy
Pathology
Radiology`

Comment: Thanks @nacho for your answer. I tried your suggestion but the result was same.

Comment: try using 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                                 echo '<a class="text" href="">' . $row['item'] . '</a><br />';
             }

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi I'd tried also your suggestion but the result was the same.

Comment: When I run the code I got the following error message: Unknown column '$parent' in 'where clause'mysqli Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function here and you can't use `$dbc` locally. Pass this variable to the function :

```php
retrieve_column($par, $dbc);
```

There is a small mistake in query. You need single quotes for the `$parent` variable :

```sql
SELECT item FROM category WHERE parent = '$parent' ORDER BY item ASC
```

And for loop a single `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))` is enaugh

```php
<?php
include ('connect.php');
include ('head.html');

echo '<div class="categ"><p class="b">Health</p>';
function retrieve_column($parent, $dbc){
    $sql = "SELECT item FROM category WHERE parent = '$parent' ORDER BY item ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        if (!$r) {
            echo "Couldn’t make a connection to DB.";
        } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                echo '<a class="text" href="">' . $row['item'] . '</a><br />';
            }
        }
    }

$par = 1;
retrieve_column($par, $dbc);
mysqli_free_r($r);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: Great job, Arash! Well done! Apreciated for your help. Now it's working correctly. Thanks again!